# Google Youtube API OOB Migration PHP

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I was using Google API OOB Method with the redirect url

```
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

But recently google just depreciated that method and now what i understand they ask migration to desktop api with loopback

```
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#redirect-uri_loopback
```

I tried that above method but its not working.

```
        $client = new Google\Client();      
        $client->setAuthConfig($dir . 'google/vendor/credentials.json');

        $socket = new SocketServer('127.0.0.1','0');
        $redirect = $socket->server;
        //$redirect = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob';

        // readyonly
        $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly'));
        $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setPrompt('consent');
        $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
```

If i change this to redirect_url to http://localhost it works but not like oob :)

Kindly suggest how it will works like it was before

**Update**

Used suggested code.

```
    $client->setRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1");
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
```

and then got this one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use `"http://127.0.0.1"` and if you have an old `credentials.json` file open it up and under redirect uris.  remove `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` the client library has not been updated to ignore it so it just takes the first redirect uri in the file, which just so happens to be `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` and that will cough up an error.

```
$client = new Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Upload quickstart');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAuthConfig('C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1");
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
```

## Update 404 error

The cause of the 404 error is because you are trying to load `"http://127.0.0.1"` on your machine without a web server running.  This will cause a 404 error to be shown by any web browser as it can not reach the webpage in question.  However if you check the url bar in the brower window you will find it states

> https://127.0.0.1/?state=xxxxxxx&code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly

The code you need to complete the authorization process is there. You simply need to copy that and paste it into your code.

Unforuantatly with the removal of oob this is the only way it will work, unless you spawn a web server to host localhost.

Note: Python is able to do this by opening a local web server

```
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

Im not sure if this is something that php can do as google has not given us an example that does this.

see [#2334](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/2334)

Comment: Thank you but i tried that code... and it works but its returned with this url 127.0.0.1/?state=xxxxxxx&code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly

Comment: Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1.

Comment: yeah that's normal the code is in the browser URL bar just grab that paste it into the console.   the code you have is going to give you the 404 its normal you don't have a web server running so 127.0.0.1 dosent exist   the authorization worked all you need is that code really

Comment: is there a way to use javascript instead of php ?

Comment: I want to get access code into input type text i don't have knowledge in javascript https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model#setup

Comment: JavaScript is a web application it will be hosted on a website.  Your creating an installed application designed to run in a console. This is two different things.    That question is unrelated to this question.   You may want to open another question if have any issues with JavaScript.